# Simple switch and case, related to cards, C language

Tags: c, playing-cards

I am trying to do a program that associates a card to a number.
I start by asking the suit, (hearts, spades, diamonds, clubs)
And then its value (ace-1, 2, 3... K-13).
When i execute this program, it always returns me the number 0, can you help me?
Sorry about the confusing words for suits or values,
i hope it does not cause any problems for you.
By the way, in portuguese 
suits: naipes;
values: valor;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char naipe;//suit
int valor;//value (ace,1,queen...)
int num;//nunumber associated to the card in question
int main(){
int naip, val;
scanf("%c", &naipe);
scanf("%d", &valor);
switch (naipe){

case 'C':
        naip= 0;
        break;
case 'E':
        naip= 13;
        break;
case 'O':
        naip= 26;
        break;
case 'P':
        naip= 39;
        break;
return naip;
        }

switch (valor){

case '1':
        val= 1;
        break;
case '2':
        val= 2;
        break;
case '3':
        val= 3;
        break;
case '4':
        val= 4;
        break;
case '5':
        val= 5;
        break;
case '6':
        val= 6;
        break;
case '7':
        val= 7;
        break;
case '8':
        val= 8;
        break;
case '9':
        val= 9;
        break;
case '10':
        val= 10;
        break;
case '11':
        val= 11;
        break;
case '12':
        val= 12;
        break;
case '13':
        val= 13;
        break;
return val;
}
num= (naip + val);

printf("%d", num);
return 0;
```

Comment: Did you not get warnings from your compiler?

Comment: Remove the single quotes from the second `switch` block. That is `'1'` should be just `1`, etc.

Comment: No, i use the Code Blocks by the way... Why?

Comment: In fact, you can remove that whole `switch` block. `valor` is already an int and can be used directly.

Comment: thanks for the help dude, maybe its reading like char values...

Comment: yes, that was exactly the problem! cool.

Answer (score 1):

`valor` is an `int`. Its values are `1`, `2`, `3`, and so on, but in the case labels, you have `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, and so on. Those are the **characters** “1”, “2”, “3”, and so on, not the integer values 1, 2, and 3. Change the case labels to `case 1:`, `case 2:`, `case 3:`, and so on. Or, better, simply use `value` as the value to be added: Since it is already the desired value, there is no reason to use a `switch` to decode it. (You might wish to add code to check whether it is in the range 1 to 13 and admonish the user if it is not. Similarly, the `switch` for `naip` could have a `default` cases that admonishes the user if the suit is not recognized. And you should check that each `scanf` returns 1, indicating it successfully converted one input.)

The values of the characters such as `'1'` are codes in a character set, such as 49 for `'1'` in ASCII. So `case '1':` is equivalent to `case 49:` (when ASCII is being used), and will not match a `valor` value of 1 to 13.

Also, when there are two characters in “single quotes”, as in `'10'`, that forms a multi-character constant. Its value is implementation-defined. There is rarely any use for such a form.

Comment: exactly the problem, very thanks for the help dude, really!